# CSS3 Animation: How do I create smooth movement of background image? Seems to be a Chrome only issue

Tags: css, css-animations

Trying to smoothly animate a `div's` background image `#bg2` over a short pixel distance (while a clip path animates over it). I'm not able to get the image to move smoothly, it jitters and judders. The clip path animation is fine.

I've tried different easing (`linear` / `ease-in-out` etc) suggested in another SO thread, and also extending the distance it needs to move, but it still seems to jump pixel by pixel (sort of), rather than move smoothly. (Although, extending the move distance isn't an option in the actual use case).

How can smooth movement of the cat background image `#bg2` be accomplished? Thanks.

** Edit: It's totally smooth for me in Firefox, for me it's jittery in Chrome 91.0.4472.114 on Mojave 10.14.6, and less jittery in Safari. For other it seems to be smooth on Chrome also. Hmmm...

```js
var clickTag = "#";
```

```css
#main-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 970px;
  height: 250px;
  left:-200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  overflow:hidden; perspective: 800px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

div, img {
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 970px;
    height: 250px;
    z-index: 4;
    background-size: 970px 250px;
}


#bg2{
    width: 970px;
    height: 250px;
    z-index:2;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EcDu.jpg');
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(9% at 682px 110px);
    clip-path: circle(9% at 682px 110px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
    background-position: -5px -10px;
}

#bg2{animation: grow 2.5s 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000) forwards;-webkit-animation: groww 2.5s 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000) forwards;}

@-webkit-keyframes groww {
 0% {opacity:1;transform: translateY(20px);clip-path: circle(9% at 682px 110px);-webkit-clip-path: circle(9% at 682px 110px);background-position: -5px -10px;}
 100% {opacity:1;transform: translateY(-4px);clip-path: circle(15% at 682px 128px);-webkit-clip-path: circle(15% at 682px 128px);background-position: 0px 0px;}
}

@keyframes grow {
 0% {opacity:1;transform: translateY(20px);clip-path: circle(9% at 682px 110px);background-position: -5px -10px;}
 100% {opacity:1;transform: translateY(-4px);clip-path: circle(15% at 682px 128px);background-position: 0px 0px;}
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
<div id="main-container" class="animate">
    <div id="bg2"></div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Looks smooth for me on Mac Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: idem for me but my computer is not overloaded with running apps, different browsers and dozens of tabs ;)

Comment: no jumping effect for me :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I'm trying to replicate something I have running locally, I just made the movement less to increase the juddering. You should be able to see it juddering now.

Comment: @RickardElimää if you look at the ending especially, it's jumping around a bunch. it's not smooth. - ** edit.  I updated the positions to try to get the jittering to show more. Can you see it now?

Comment: I'm afraid to be of no help,.  it still is smooth on my computer's screen.

Comment: Why does the background-image have a huge white area to the left?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus thanks for taking another look. I see it's totally smooth for me on Firefox, but not for me on Chrome 91.0.4472.114  on Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Totally smooth for me, too - I'm using firefox 89.0.2 on Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: @Rickard Elimää these are 970x250 ad banners, all the images are 970x250 pngs in the actual use case, I just tried to mock up a test version that would replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes, I see a slight 'jitter' on Chrome (Windows 10).

Comment: I am not clear why you need to move the cats' image  - I can see the calculations needed to effect that while also clipping could run into say rounding errors. But if you do need to then how about separating that from the growing circle (which could be done with a mask on another background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit curious about why having a large banner while not displaying it all.

Anyways, I provide another way of animating, basically just changing the height. Hopefully that could give some ideas.

I removed the width to make it slightly more responsive.

The animation somewhat jittery in this solution, but I guess that it depends on your bezier curve. So perhaps that's the issue all along?

```js
var clickTag = "#";
```

```css
#main-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #333;
}

#bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  height: 40%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;

  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EcDu.jpg');
  background-position: right 25% center;
  
  animation: grow 2.5s 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000) forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
  to { height: 80%; }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="bg2"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying!  It's client work so I had to come up with a slimmed down test version of the problem :D